# It is possible to generate Builder using google auto-value outside class?

Tags: android, builder-pattern, auto-value

I have class and builder for it.

Builder would be used only in test code and I would like not to have it in production code.

My class:

```
public class MyClassThatIWantBuilderFor {
  // many fields that I want initialize using builder instead of 10 arg constructor
}
```

My test case:

```
public class MyTest {
  // I want to have builder for MyClassThatIWantBuilderFor class here
}
```

How to achieve it in auto-value?

Comment: This isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: what is the purpose of `MyClassThatIWantBuilderFor` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt This is my model class that has approx. 10 fields in constructor and I want to have builder for it.

Comment: it is really unclear to me as well. What do you mean by *I would like not to have it in production code* ? If you don't want it in `main/` put that only in your test project?

Comment: @Blackbelt I want to have builder in test code and model class in production code, since I would use builder only in tests. The reason for such approach is dreaded 65k method limit in Android...

Comment: isn't the multidex support an option for you?

Comment: @Blackbelt Due to variety of devices multidex support causes many problems - on some low-end devices startup time can increase to 2-3s. There are also buggy devices that crash when multidex is enabled ( Samsung Galaxy S5). That's why I want to fit into 65k method limit and do such things like this one stated in my question.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by auto-value.. like deserializing? single constructor? That part makes no sense, but what you said above, sounds like you want to be able to deserialize a model.. ?

Comment: @JustinMitchell by auto-value I mean library made by Google https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/builders.md

Comment: Ok so why dont you implement the builder pattern yourself? Also why would you test different functionality than production? Thats not going to help much.